# How to push 2D Array with Form Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I am new to JavaScript and don't know why my 2D array (each primary row element having both 'Word' and 'Color Value' column elements) is not being updated with user inputted form values? Also why it is not displaying the array? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        Your current list of words to search:
        <p id = "Array"> </p>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form>
        Input Word:<br><br>
        <input type="text" id="wordInputId" ><br>

        <br> Highlight Color: <select name="colortype" id="colorTypeId">
        <br>
        <br>
        <option value="1">Blue</option>
        <option value="2">Green</option>
        <option value="3">Red</option>
        <option value="4">Yellow</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Word" onclick="addEntry(   inventory, document.getElementById('wordInputId').value, document.getElementById('colorTypeId').value )"/>
    </form>

    <br>

    <button> Search Page</button>

    <script src="Words.js">

        var inventory = [[]];
        displayInventory(inventory);

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

JS Functions (Words.js):

```
function displayInventory(inventory){
    document.getElementById("Array").innerHTML = inventory.toString();
}


function addEntry(inventory, word, color){
    inventory.push([[word.value],[color.value]]);
    //displayInventory(inventory);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `src` and script lines in same script tag is a wrong way to define your scripts. First you need to seperate them. Then your `displayInventory` function only called once when script is compiled. You can check it by binding it on click event. Also you don't need to send `inventory` array with button. It will be defined in script already. Also you are getting `values` second time on your code. It means you are trying to get value of value and this is bad. Check this code please.

```js
var inventory = [[]];
function displayInventory(inventory){
    document.getElementById("Array").innerHTML = inventory.toString();
}
function addEntry(word, color){
    inventory.push([[word],[color]]);
    displayInventory(inventory);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>   
    <body>
    Your current list of words to search:
    <p id = "Array"> </p>
    <form>
        Input Word:<br><br>
        <input type="text" id="wordInputId" ><br>
        <br> Highlight Color: <select name="colortype" id="colorTypeId">
        <br>
        <br>
        <option value="1">Blue</option>
        <option value="2">Green</option>
        <option value="3">Red</option>
        <option value="4">Yellow</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Add Word" onclick="addEntry(document.getElementById('wordInputId').value, document.getElementById('colorTypeId').value)"/>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button> Search Page</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have both a `src` attribute and a body on a `script` tag. You can have either one.

So, you should structure it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Words.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var inventory = [[]];
    displayInventory(inventory);

</script>
```